# Dynamically Create Menu Items based on an Observable List

Tags: java, javafx

I have an observable list of type Playlist.

I have a dropdown menu (connected to a `MenuButton`) with a `MenuItem` for each item in the list (plus a few default items I hard code that don't change).

For a `TableView`, I am able to link the data to an ObservableList, and the table's rows automatically update based on the contents of the List.

Is there a way to do the same thing for a `MenuButton` and its list of `MenuItem`s?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is built in support but either way, you can write a wrapper for any element you want based off an `ObservableList` by writing a listener. For example,

```
public class BoundMenuButton extends MenuButton {

    ObservableList<MenuItem> items;

    public BoundMenuButton(items) {
        super(); // Not sure if needed
        this.items = items;

        // Listen for changes
        items.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends MenuItem> change) -> {
            updateItems();
        });
    }

    public void updateItems() {
        Platform.runLater( () -> {
            // Do updates
        });
    }
}
```

This is just the very basics. You can extend this to have the same methods as a `TableView` fairly easily. (`getItems()`, `setItems()`, etc.).

*P.S - This code is untested as I don't have access to a compiler currently.*

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna give this a shot. I'll let you know how it goes, thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaD No prob, let me know if you need any more help :)